# Workflow removal from List created based on other list template

Tags: list, workflow

## Scenario:

I have created once one list and it has two workflow which can be activated based on New item created and when item change.

I have save that list as template. Now i have created New list using that template.

### Problem:

Since I have created the list based on other list, the new list sharing same workflow as old list. How do i can remove the workflow from new list but i do not want to remove same workflow from old list. The workflow is normal list workflow.

If some one can help in this regards.

Thanks.

Chintesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing a workflow from a list or library does not delete the actual source files used to compile the workflow. Rather, the workflow is no longer attached to the list or library, but the source files remain stored in the Workflows document library of the site. To delete the workflow, see the next section.

1. In a Web browser, browse to the site that contains the workflow that you want to delete, and then browse to the specific list or library to which the workflow is attached.
2. On the list or library menu bar, click **Settings**, and then click either **List Settings** or **Document Library Settings**, whichever is present.
3. Under **Permissions and Management**, click **Workflow Settings**.
4. On the Change Workflow Settings page, click **Remove a workflow**.

> Note: You can use the option Add a workflow to make a workflow that
>   was previously removed available again. But note that a workflow that
>   was designed in Office SharePoint Designer 2007 is always attached to
>   exactly one list or library. You can add a workflow only to the list
>   or library to which it was originally attached.

5. On the Remove Workflows page, click Remove, and then click OK.
6. Click OK to confirm that you want to remove the workflow.

**Note:-** Above Example is for SharePoint 2007 (I provided it for SP 2007 as you didn't mentioned your SharePoint version ) but it works same for all SharePoint Environments.

Comment: My Pleasure.Happy to help you .:)